# Should I manually update dependencies versions in the package.json after creating a new project with npm?

Tags: npm, package.json, vuetify.js

I've installed this boilerplate with Electron and Vuetify frameworks included: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/electron

### Questions:

Should I now manually change those versions in the `package.json` to the latest  and run `npm install` again?

```
 "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.4.2",
    "vuetify": "0.17.4",
    "vue-electron": "^1.0.6",
    [...]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.7.5",
    [...]
  }
```

Why do those dependencies have that `^` symbol if they still don't download the latest version?

The boilerplate has this code in one of the components and it's displaying the installed versions:

```
<script>
 export default {
    data () {
      return {
        electron: process.versions['atom-shell'],
        node: process.versions.node,
        vue: require('vue/package.json').version
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

It shows that it uses the latest version of vuejs (v2.5.13) but ancient versions of node and electron:

[image]

- `Electron: 1.7.10` even though in the `package.json` I see `"electron": "^1.7.5"` while the latest version is `1.8.2`. Why is that?
- And `Node: 7.9.0` which I don't even see it in the `package.json`. How do I update it to `9.5.0`? I suppose, updating Electron will update node automatically, is that how it works?

Comment: `npm install` will ignore updates if package is already installed. You might want to run `npm update` I think.

Comment: @Traxo thanks for the suggestion, though why does it downloads `"electron": "^1.7.10"` instead of the the latest `1.8.2` in the first place? Does this `^` symbol means "install the latest bug fix" - `v0.0.x` ? How do I make it to install THE latest possible version there is?

Comment: `^1.7.10` is method for `1.x.x`. I'm not sure why it didn't get latest `1.x.x` on your initial setup tho. To install latest possible stable ( i.e `x.x.x`) you can just type `stable` I think (and then `npm update`). But I wouldn't recommend it due to possible breaking changes when you update. Additionally you can run `npm install electron@latest --save`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I worked with `npm-packages` it is possible to manually change the `npm-package` version to required but available version. Just after making changes in `package.json` you can install the dependencies or run `npm install` and it will install the specified package to project directory.

The tilde(~) sign shows that the rightmost value of specific package version will increment upto the latest available version value that was published. In short, the version `~1.1.2` will match and can update upto all `1.1.X` versions of that specific package but will not match or update `1.2.0` version. While `~1.2` will match and can update upto `1.2.*` through to `1.X.*`.

The caret(^) sign allows you to update package to most recent major version (referencing to the first number of package version). i.e. `^1.1.2` will match any `1.x.x` release including `1.2.0`, but will not match or update `2.0.0`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me:

```
1. npm update vue
```

If you got error :

> vue-template-compiler and vue should be the same version

then run 2 and 3 step

```
2. npm uninstall vue-template-compiler 
3. npm install vue-template-compiler
```