# npm install not getting latest minor version of package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a colleague who's having issues with npm install, I'm wondering if anyone else has had the same issue...

Win 10 x64

Node 8.9.3

Global npm packages installed:

- npm 5.6.0
- rimraf 2.6.2

(We have multiple PCs all running identical node/npm versions for consistency, so this can't be updated on a whim)

We have a package json with a dev dependency of "typescript": ^"2.0.6"

On all other dev machines, doing npm install on a fresh clone of our repo (no node_modules / typings), we get given typescript 2.7.2, the latest minor version of typescript to date.

On this one machine, we are given 2.6.2, consistently.

We have completely uninstalled node, removed %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\npm & %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache to no avail.

For completeness we have also run npm cache verify.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, we are stumped.

Comment: No package-lock ?

Comment: No, no package-lock in the repo as it stands. In a seemingly random twist though, we have just pulled the repo down again (Same machine, same global packages etc. and no updates to repo since before we started having the issue) and it has just pulled down the correct latest package version (2.7.2).

Comment: Why not ? It prevents this kind of issue.

Comment: I couldn't say why not, I am fairly new to npm and this was a pre-existing repo. It may help prevent the issue going forward, but does not explain the actual incorrect behaviour..

Answer (score -1):

Might be the same problem here. I think below link helps you to get more about working with package versions.

as you specified that you have a `package.json` with a dev dependency of "typescript": ^"2.0.6".

Just try by replacing the below line in your `package.json` file.

"typescript": "exact version you needed"

Ex. "typescript": "2.0.6"

Including with this before running `npm install` just delete the `package-lock.json` file from your projects root directory if any.

[Should I manually update dependencies versions in the package.json after creating a new project with npm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48771001/should-i-manually-update-dependencies-versions-in-the-package-json-after-creatin/48825447#48825447)

Comment: Hi! Can you extract the main ideas from the link and put them directly into the answer? Generally, link-only answers are discouraged on SO. Thanks!

Comment: can you please brief me what the actual issue you are facing while running `npm install`. Or you want to install the exact version of "typescript" package? So i can help you more specific and correct.

Comment: As described in question, version of typescript package in package.json is ^"2.0.6", has '^' to fetch latest minor version, but on one machine it is pulling 2.6.2 (not the latest minor version, but equally not the originally installed version of 2.0.6). To clarify, it *should* be installing version 2.7.2 based on the syntax.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding. I have updated the answer. Hope this is helpful to you.